# R: How to pass an object to a function?

Tags: r, function, oop

I'm newbie in R and I'm trying to pass an object to a function but I've got an error when I try to access to a slot of this object.

These are my main code:

```
x <- new("menu", competition=0, stats=0, query="")
y <- show(x)
show_graphics(y)
```

After second instruction I've got the object "y" created correctly like you can see in this screencap:

[image]

Then, I call to a the function "show_graphics" and pass this object "y" like a parameter. But when I try to access to an slot in the first insctruction of my function:

```
show_graphics <- function(menu){
  data <- getData(menu@query)
  ......
}
```

> I've got an error that tell me that there is an error to try to access
>   to the slot "query" of an object to the basic class "function" without
>   slots.

How can I pass correctly an object to a function? Or how can I get the values from an object passed to a function?

Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit I:**

This is the code to create the object "menu":

```
setClass("menu", slots=list(competition="numeric", stats="numeric", query="character"))
show <- function(object) 0
setGeneric("show")
setMethod("show", "menu", function(object){
  object@competition <- 14
  object@stats <- 1
  object@query <- "query"
  return (object)
})
```

**Edit II:**

getData is another function, here is the code of a prototype:

```
getData <- function(query){
   return (query)
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to re-produce. When I try to run the `x <- new(..` line, I get the error: `Error in getClass(Class, where = topenv(parent.frame())) : 
  “menu” is not a defined class`. Are you able to include all relevant code, please?

Comment: I have edited my original post where I have added a prototype of the menu object

Comment: Thank you. I'm still struggling unfortunately. `y <- show(x)` gives me the error `Error in show(x) : object 'competition' not found` & `show_graphics(y)` gives me the error `Error in getData(menu@query) : could not find function "getData"`. Might be worth making a simpler version of the problem that's fully re-producible

Comment: Sorry, I have forget to return the object. I have updated the code from Edit I and created an function prototype of getData in Edit II

Comment: Thank you. It's weird, I don't get any error when running `show_graphics(y)` now (if I remove the ......). Unrelated but you could try using `R6` classes for object orientated approach. It's well supported with good documentation: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/r6.html

Comment: I have testes with the protorypes and I'm nota getting any error too. I don't know what happend!!! I'll checkout the documentation that Youtube recommend me. Thank you so mucho for your help @Jonny Phelps!!!